# Problem with connect Flutter App API server

Tags: node.js, api, flutter

Any one can support me .. i tired to connect to me API but i got error ,,
My Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List> getData() async {
String url = 'http://localhost:4000/api/contacts';
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
return json.decode(response.body);
}

void main() async {
List data = await (getData());
print(data);
}
```

but i got error

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 7,213ms.
E/flutter ( 5291): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 5291): type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'
E/flutter ( 5291): #0      getData (package:json/main.dart:13:3)
E/flutter ( 5291): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5291): #1      main (package:json/main.dart:17:22)
E/flutter ( 5291): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5291): #2      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:289:19)
E/flutter ( 5291): #3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
```

,, any advice

[My API server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFgrh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the return type for the method like this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData() async {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i just put the object inside list, Then it worked fine ... Thanks